# Is there a way to know if a computer have been in a domain, even if now it not

Tags: windows, active-directory

in Windows, and maybe in system logs, is there a way to find if a computer have been in an Active Directory domain, even if now it is not.

Does a log message trace join or quit a domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a log for joining a domain.
Run `eventvwr.msc` > Windows Logs > System. Filter Current Log by event ID 3260.
Also, when you quit a domain it means you joined a workgroup and the event ID you should filter in this case is 3261.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for